# iOS: bug in AVPlayerItem when receiving `304 Not Modified` response

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset, avplayeritem

This is a very weird bug.

I have a tableView with each cell using an `AVPlayer` to stream a video from a remote server (think a Vine-like timeline). So when I scroll, the cells that get reused reconfigure their player with the new video.

The problem is: if I scroll back and forth very fast, getting the same video in and out of the screen, the request sent by the AVPlayer eventually changes, to include the HTTP Headers `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since`, which are not there the rest of the time. It systematically makes the server return a `304 Not Modified` response.

That doesn't seem to please the AVPlayer's playerItem, which changes its status to `AVPlayerItemStatusFailed` (interestingly, the AVPlayer's status is still `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`). The error is `AVErrorUnknown` (-11800) with an OSStatus -12983 (which isn't documented anywhere and is in no header in the entire iOS SDK).

That's when it gets weird: whatever I do next, the AVPlayer and its playerItem are irrevocably burnt. Even if I reconfigure them with another asset, they'll just return this status and show a black frame. Weirder still: even if I initialize another AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem *and* AVAsset, it just won't play anymore, I have to kill and restart the app.

At this point, I'm pretty clueless. Any idea what's happening here? Preventing the player from including these headers in its connection would fix it, but it's not exposing its request serializer.

Answer (score 1):

#### 304 Not Modified

I have encountered `304 Not Modified` response, which happens when AVPlayer replay same video, and `AVPlayerItem.status` becomes `failed`, detail error is `content range mismatch - should be start 0 length 2 is start 0 length 1048575`. **But**, the difference is that playback is normal if `AVPlayer` switch to play other video.

Detail Http request and response example:

> **Request part**
>   If-Modified-Since: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 03:41:12 GMT
>   Range:bytes=0-1
>
> **Response part**
>   HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
>   Content-Range: bytes 0-1048575/13852554

**Solution**:
Modify server-side logic, change `Content-Range` value to `bytes 0-1/13852554` or delete `Content-Range` directly, then playback will start normally.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. so I add `If-None-Match: ${unique value}` header to prevent return 304. it work to me.

```swift
    var player = AVQueuePlayer()
    func play(url: String) {
        let headers = ["If-None-Match": "1"]
        let options = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers]
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!, options: options)
        let playItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playItem)
        player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        player.playImmediately(atRate: 1)
    }
```