# 304 Not modified when playing html5 video on iOS Cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, video

I'm loading an external (Vimeo) .mp4 into a standard HTML5 Video tag within an Ionic Framework app, which is working fine except on iOS:

Vimeo's external link (e.g. `https://player.vimeo.com/external/` ) forwards to an `https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net` address as they describe [here](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Direct-links).

On iOS the initial load is loaded from `Source: Disk Cache`. However, when navigating away from this page, or stopping and trying to replay the video, it returns a `Status: 304 Not Modified` response as it expects the video to be loaded from the cache again I expect. However, within the app the video is not loaded from cache and I just get a broken player (with the source not found).

The video Tag looks Like this:

```
<div class="player">
  <video class="player__video viewer toggle" #exerciseVideo [src]="exercise.video | vimeoVideoUrl | safe:'resourceUrl'" [poster]="exercise.images[0] | awsImageUrl:'medium' | safe:'resourceUrl'" controls playsinline loop tappable></video>
</div>
```

Any help on how to load it from cache on the second play (ideally), or how to force a fresh network request each time would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything on this including the following posts:

[iOS: bug in AVPlayerItem when receiving `304 Not Modified` response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243822/ios-bug-in-avplayeritem-when-receiving-304-not-modified-response/)

[Embedded HTML 5 video is stored in the cache but is not displayed on iPad 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079756/embedded-html-5-video-is-stored-in-the-cache-but-is-not-displayed-on-ipad-2/18065811#18065811)

However the absolute nuclear option I have had to implement to get this to work on iOS is the appending `?time-in-milliseconds`

Done using the following code as an example:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const currentTime = currentDate.getTime();
return `${environment.VIMEO_SRC}${videoInput.video}${environment.VIMEO_SPEC_TRAIL}?${currentTime}`;
```

Welcome any other feedback.